# Is adding empty JLabels an expensive process?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am trying to do something like below in Java, but and I have tried a `BorderLayout` so far (for the upper panel).

[image]

The problem with that approach is that I cannot add in a "HELP" button. So, I am vying for the `GridBagLayout`. The problem with that approach is that I might have to either add a bunch of empty `JLabel`s or just forget the whole `upperPanel` idea, and just add directly to the `JFrame` (which would be a cheaper process because I don't have to use a resource-heavy `JPanel`, but probably wouldn't look as good).

Would you advise against adding a bunch of empty `JLabel`s?

Comment: Are you using an IDE? or are you trying to setup your layout by code all by sourself? And what amount of "bunch" are we talking here? ^^

Comment: I am using Eclipse, and yes, I am trying to setup the layout code "all by myself". According to the picture, I figured the top to require `O(8)` columns (because the table has that many). The `JLabel` with the instructions and the `JComboBox` should take up `O(3)`, while the button should take up 1. That leaves `O(5)` empty spots on the top that would have to be filled if I am to house this all in the `upperPanel`.

Comment: Does eclipse not have a gui editor? I would recommend that, netbeans has one ;) Any why do you use O-Notation? ^^ Besides that, i sadly can´t help you.

Comment: I use O-Notation because my estimates are just that: estimates. Also, I didn't see a GUI Editor. //So it is just me, my brainpower, and if it gets really, REALLY messy, this forum...

Comment: Hmm, no GUI is bad -.- sorry for poiting the O-Notation out, but i can´t stop myself because you are using it wrong: O(1) = O(3) = O(5) = O(8) = basically every number -> O(constant) don´t get you anywhere.

Comment: and the number of empty spaces for both of the rows of content (in the upper part of the frame) per row is 4, not 5. //I tried to correct that; it was a typo, but it wouldn't let me. Also, thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Consider using a BoxLayout for the overall layout and a GridBagLayout for just the top "box" the top 1/3. And no, adding JLabel's is not very expensive.

Comment: I don't understand yet what you want to do and what the problem is. The phrases like "... I cannot add in a Help button..." and "... vying for GridBagLayout..." and "...I might have to either add a bunch of empty JLabels..." just don't tell us what you're trying to do.  Is the "click this button for more help" rectangle an example of a help button that you want?  Does it interfere with some layout you already have?  Is that where you want it and you don't know how to put it there?

Comment: *" because I don't have to use a resource-heavy `JPanel`"*  Panels are not 'resource heavy'.

Comment: I predicted that someone would bring this up in specific, but I was "lost in the code" and couldn't do anything about it. No, it isn't an extra button; it is simply a ToolTip for the "Help" button

Comment: GridBagLayout has thus neat feature(?) where you can add multiple components to the same cell with different constraints ;)

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? It was a serious question that exhibited serious thought and serious effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is adding empty JLabels an expensive process?

No, it is not.

Comment: @Mike Warren `a bunch of empty JLabels?` equals for me JList or JTable

Answer (score 1):

I also found this about Fillers (my reason for asking this simple question):http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.Filler.html

Comment: Or you can achieve the same behaviour by Nesting various Layouts as suggested by @AndrewThompson, in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/1057230)